# Getting the name of a unifiable predicate

Tags: prolog

How can I get the name of a predicate that can unify with given inputs.
Something that would have this effect (if it actually worked):

```
findpredicate( A, B, P ) :- P(A,B).
```

Some way to cycle through the existing predicates and find one to whom the given inputs are true. I need to just get the name.

Comment: [`current_predicate/1`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dcurrent_005fpredicate.html#index-current_005fpredicate_002f_005b1_002c2_005d-_0028built_002din_002c-ref-page_0029-4539) and  [`predicate_property`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dpredicate_005fproperty.html#mpg_002dref_002dpredicate_005fproperty) and `call/3`

Comment: @false
Yes, the combination of those was exactly what I was looking for, although I had to use modules to get it work right. How about submitting an answer so I can tag it as correct?